# Multiple includes on different depths in a LoopBack/Node.js query

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I'm  trying to load an object on a node.js Loopback server and I want to load multiple related objects in the same query. These related objects are on different depths. This is the query:

```
/api/MyUsers/114?filter[include][institutes]=institute&filter[include]=departments&filter[include]=profiles
```

Notice that *[institutes]=institute* have two levels and *departments* and *profiles* only one.

This returns me an error:
**500 Internal server error. Error: Relation "0" is not defined for User model.**

On node.js debug I noticed that the final JSON query generated seems to be wrong:

```
{ include: 
     { '0': 'departments',
       '1': 'profiles',
       institutes: 'institute' } },
     ...
}
```

Here is the model for MyUser:

```
{
  "name": "MyUser",
  "plural": "MyUsers",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mixins": {
    "Versioning": true,
    "Tenant": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "departments": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "UserDepartment",
      "foreignKey": "user_id"
    },
    "institutes": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "UserInstitute",
      "foreignKey": "user_id"
    },
    "profiles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "UserProfile",
      "foreignKey": "user_id"
    },
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Has anyone else faced this problem? Is it a loopback bug? If so, how can I turn around for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

**500 Internal server error. Error: Relation "0" is not defined for User model.**

This error says that your User model does not have a relation which is called departaments. In your definition of the User model, make sure that you added a relation for the departaments model. (By the way, if `departaments` is an English word, it has a spelling problem, `departments` is correct.)

As this [link](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html) says:

> An include filter enables you to include results from related models
>   in a query, for example, models that have belongsTo or hasMany
>   relations, to optimize the number of requests.

This link can help you to define a relation for your model:

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/defining-and-mapping-data-relations-with-loopback-connected-models/

If you are using the built-in User model, you can extend it as below link says:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Extending-built-in-models.html

**Edit After Comment:**

One more explanation about filters:

The meaning of filter[include][institutes]=institute filter is:

Include 'institutes' which is a relation of User and also include 'institute' which is a relation of 'institutes'.
I tested this feature in one of my projects and it works fine.

Comment: The question is that departments is defined. As you can see the final include JSON is not properly generated, that '0' should not bee there, so it's working like if '0' was a relation, and it's not.

Comment: Could you add your models in the question as well? I think Loopback assumes that all the includes are related to the User model. Can you show in your model definition that what do you want to include in which level?

Comment: I've added the model above in the question.

Comment: Did you try to run your query with just one include at a time? What is the response when you run the query with including just departments relation?

Comment: The model which you provided generate this error: **Error: Cyclic dependency: "User"**

Comment: With just one include It Works. It's giving this error because I'm using fake names in the example, my class shouldn't be User because it already exists in loopback. I'll edit the example.

Comment: I can't help you if you don't give me enough information. Could you create a sample code which I can access and check the error? I need all your models information, a working example could be great.