# Loopbackjs Querying related model via rest api

Tags: node.js, rest, api, loopbackjs, loopback

is there any way to query related model's related model like from `post` \Get:

```
{"order": "created_at DESC","include":[{"relation": "user"}]
```

But, in my `user` model there is a relation `hasone` with `settings` model. I want to get that also, while querying from `post` \Get rest api. I've tried with:

```
{ "include": { "relation": "user","include": {"relation":"settings"}}}
```

but no luck.

Comment: Maybe my answer to another question helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760175/multiple-includes-on-different-depths-in-a-loopback-node-js-query/45769344#45769344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've create nested relationship to related to your question.

example : teamRole.json

TeamRole > belongTo > User and Team

```
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "team": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Team",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "User",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
```

Retrieve results

```
app.models.TeamRole.findOne({
      where: {
        userId: user.id
      },
      include:[ {
        relation: 'team'
      },
{
        relation: 'user'
      } ]
    },function(err,team,user){
//retrieve relational data here
});
```

Try this approach, hope this will helpful.